# How to insert null value into DateTime column? 

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to store a null value into a `DateTime` column. My code is like below:

```
protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ChangeModule cm = new ChangeModule();
        cm.CR_REF_NO = txtCRRefNumber.Text.Trim();
        cm.SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER = DateTime.ParseExact(txtSLADeliveryDateWaiver.Text, "dd/MM/yy", null);
        else /*This else part is causing problem since I assigned null*/
             cm.SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw ex;
    }
}
```

Code is working fine as long as a proper date exists in SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER, but throwing error when there is the blank textbox.

Comment: did you try the DateTime? var = null;

Comment: try out DateTime.TryParseExact()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem to send null values into date-parameters inside the sql server stored procedires. Hence, whenever there is a need to pass null date from front-end application, pass some min. date like '1/1/1753' for example.

Inside SQL Server stored procedure, check for the null date like below:

```
IF DATEDIFF(DD, @DATE, '1/1/1753') = 0
    SET @DATE = NULL
```

Now, you can use @DATE inside SQL Server stored procedure however you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a `DateTime` property to null, because `DateTime` is a value type. You'll need to change it to a `Nullable<DateTime>` (aka `DateTime?`) property - and then make sure that's handled appropriately in your storage layer. It's unclear what's performing the database interaction at the moment.

You should read up on [Nullable Value Types on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

You'll also need to change your code to actually have an `if` statement, e.g.

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtSLADeliveryDateWaiver.Text,
                           "dd/MM/yy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    cm.SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER = dt;
}
else
{
    cm.SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER = null;
}
```

(You should also get rid of the try/catch block - it's actually *harming* your code as it'll currently mask the source of exceptions, even aside from cluttering it up.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. While declaring the "ChangeModule" class I have declared SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER field as Nullable only.

Comment: @Ashok: It's not clear what you mean, but it needs to be of type `Nullable<DateTime>`.

Comment: My problem is that null date is not inserting in the database as I have specified in my post.
Showing the following error: Now, as well as before also:

Procedure or function 'usp_SaveECR' expects parameter '@SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER', which was not supplied.

Comment: @Ashok: Well that's going to be part of the code you haven't shown. You've only shown the UI code - not the code which is talking to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you make SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER a nullable DateTime then you can do this:

```
 protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ChangeModule cm = new ChangeModule();
            cm.CR_REF_NO = txtCRRefNumber.Text.Trim();
            cm.SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSLADeliveryDateWaiver.Text)? null : DateTime.ParseExact(txtSLADeliveryDateWaiver.Text, "dd/MM/yy", null);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got this following error with the solution you have provided: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.DateTime'

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made myself clear enough. My code example requires SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER to be made nullable. It looks like a lot of people are saying the same thing. Basically, in the ChangeModule class you have to change the line that says DateTime SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER to DateTime? SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER. This  can have big repercussions in your app, though, so do this carefully and with lots of testing. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` can't have `null` value but, adding question mark '?' in front or DateTime data type while declaring makes it nullable, something like this:

```
DateTime? nullableDateTime = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is not Nullable per se, you need to specify it as a Nullable, as already noted.

So

```
DateTime SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER { get; set; }
```

wont work, you need to do

```
DateTime? SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER { get; set; }
```

or

```
Nullable<DateTime> SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER { get; set; }
```

Are you storing this to a database? You need the column to be nullable too then.

Comment: Yeah, I have done like this already. My problem is with the stored procedure insert statement.

Comment: @Ashok Wouldn't harm if you would show that proc and the exact exception text in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You got exception when there is the blank textbox because [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) thrown an FormatException when string to parse is an empty string. 
Use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) instead.

From your question it looks like `cm.SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER` is `DateTime`, change its type to `DateTime?` so in case of empty textbox:
 - `TryParseExact()` will not fail
 - `cm.SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER` will be able to store NULL value

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the stored procedure works, but I think its a bit sloppy.

You can handle it in code, this work for me:

```
            DateTime? myDate;

        if (TextBoxWithDate.Text != "")
        {
            myDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxWithDate.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            myDate = null;
        }
```

Make myDate DateTime type but nullable, if the value from the text box is null, make myDate null and send it to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dtProcessStart.Text.Trim() == "")
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProcessStartDttm", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: try this, while passing parameter to store procedure..  DBNULL.Value

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    ChangeModule cm = new ChangeModule();
    cm.CR_REF_NO = txtCRRefNumber.Text.Trim();
    cm.SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER = DateTime.ParseExact(txtSLADeliveryDateWaiver.Text, "dd/MM/yy", null);
    else
         cm.SLA_DELIVERY_DATE_WAIVER = DBNULL.Value;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```